# Scala pattern-matching confusion

Tags: scala

I start learning Scala and I don't quite understand some behaviors of pattern-matching. Can anyone explain to me why the first case works but the second case doesn't work?

## 1

```
def getFirstElement(list: List[Int]) : Int = list match {
    case h::tail => h
    case _ => -1
}

Scala> getFirstElement(List(1,2,3,4))
res: Int = 1

Scala> 1 :: List(1,2)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2)
```

## 2

```
def getSumofFirstTwoElement(list: List[Int]): Int = list match {
    case List(a: Int, b: Int)++tail => a + b
    case _ => -1
}

<console>:11: error: not found: value ++

Scala> List(1,2) ++ List(3,4,5)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that there is no `unapply` method on an object of type `++`.  The reason that `::` works is because behind the scenes it is really:

```
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1)

This leads to how pattern matching is implemented in Scala. It uses [extractors](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html) (or [here](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html)), which are basically objects that contain an `unapply` method, which is provided by default with case classes.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that this works as hd :: tl because it ends with a :, which signifies that it can be used in this right associative way. I started to come up with a way to get your ++ to work, but it just would not be pretty

Answer (score 1):

`++` is a method on object of list. I think you want:

```
def getSumofFirstTwoElement(list: List[Int]): Int = list match {
     case a::b::tail => a + b
     case _ => -1
}
```

Comment: This works. I understand ++ method is a method on object of list. Why can't I use this in match-case pattern? Thanks.

Comment: As Justin described, its because of unapply that turns the object into its components.

Answer (score 1):

In case two, `++` isn't used for unapply. You want the extractor `::` to decompose the list.

A good explanation [here](http://blog.lunatech.com/2011/11/25/scala-list-extractor-demystified).

```
scala> def getSumofFirstTwoElement(list: List[Int]): Int = list match {
     |     case a::b::t => a + b
     |     case _ => -1
     | }
getSumofFirstTwoElement: (list: List[Int])Int


scala> getSumofFirstTwoElement(List(1,2,3,4))
res0: Int = 3
```